# Read output of an oracle query with a bash script

Tags: bash, if-statement, oracle10g

I am trying to setup a bash script within which a connection to an Oracle instance to check the various dba jobs scheduled and if a specific job is not running i need to display an error message.

Here is the script i have written and it works partially, the script works only until it reaches the IF statement

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#write output of the sql query to an output file 
output_file="/tmp/datatool_output.csv"
> $output_file

echo "
SET FEED OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET COLSEP ,
SET linesize 100
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET TRIMOUT ON


SELECT JOB_NAME, STATE FROM DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS where job_name ='run_LoadDatatoolStore';

exit" | sqlplus -s sqlplus -s "username/password@dbip:dbport/SID" >> $output_file

     a_var=($(awk -F',' '{print $2}' $output_file | sed 's/\s//g' | xargs))


for item in ${a_var[@]}
 do
val=$(echo $item  | awk -F',' '{print $1}')

if [[ $val -eq "SCHEDULED"  ]] || [[  $val -eq "RUNNING" ]] ; then
     echo "OK: The job LoadDatatool is either Scheduled or in the Running state"
     exit 0 # this is used for interpretation by nagios to display no alert alert
else [[ $val -eq "BLOCKED" ]]
     echo "CRITICAL: The Db scheduler job LoadDatatool is in a Blocked state"
      exit 2
fi
```

I get

```
test.sh: line 24: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

when i run the script Any help figuring this out is appreciated.

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: Try to change `[[ $val -eq "SCHEDULED"  ]] || [[  $val -eq "RUNNING" ]]` to `[[ $val -eq "SCHEDULED" || $val -eq "RUNNING" ]]`

Comment: @Ivan , it is still the same the syntax there is not the issue I think

Comment: And `-eq` have to be changet to `=` as @RomeoNinov said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rewrite your `if` on this way:

```
if [[ $val -eq "SCHEDULED"  ]] || [[  $val -eq "RUNNING" ]] ; then
```

to be

```
if [[ $val = "SCHEDULED"  ]] || [[  $val = "RUNNING" ]] ; then
```

or

```
if [[ $val = "SCHEDULED"  || $val = "RUNNING" ]] ; then
```

`-eq` is used to compare numbers, `=` is used to compare strings

P.S. Also instead of redirect output of `sqlplus` you can use `SPOOL` feature of `sqlplus`
And instead of this ugly `echo` you can write `sql` in file and exec it from command line like:

```
sqlplus -s "username/password@dbip:dbport/SID" @sql_script.sql
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction . Replacing 'eq' with '=' did the job

Answer (score 1):

Add **done** at the end of the script